# how to get Monday as first day in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

if you run the code snippet, you'll see that Monday is day number 7, how can I get Monday as the first day of the week
example:
Monday 05/01/2017 the week No. 1
Tuesday 05/02/2017 the week No. 2

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2017, 1, 27);
  var roster = ['work', 'off', 'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'work',
   'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'off', 'off', 'work'];
  $('#date').datepicker({minDate: weekStart, onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var week = Math.floor(days / 7) % 2;
    $('#week').val(week + 1);
    $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
    $('#work').val(roster[week * 7 + date.getDay() - 1]);
  }});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
<p>Day: <input type="text" id="day"></p>
<p>week: <input type="text" id="week"></p>
<p>work: <input type="text" id="work"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"you'll see that Monday is day number 7"_?

Comment: run it and se week nr in Monday is week nr 1 and Tuesday is week nr 2

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `firstDay: 1` param.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2017, 1, 27);
  var roster = ['work', 'off', 'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'work',
   'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'off', 'off', 'work'];
  $('#date').datepicker({ firstDay: 1,  minDate: weekStart, onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var week = Math.floor(days / 7) % 2;
    $('#week').val(week + 1);
    $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
    $('#work').val(roster[week * 7 + date.getDay() - 1]);
  }});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
<p>Day: <input type="text" id="day"></p>
<p>week: <input type="text" id="week"></p>
<p>work: <input type="text" id="work"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run it and se week nr in Monday is week nr 1 and Tuesday is week nr 2

Answer (score 0):

my answer is month to 0 
var weekStart = new Date(2017, 0, 27);

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2017, 0, 27);
  var roster = ['work', 'off', 'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'work',
   'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'off', 'off', 'work'];
  $('#date').datepicker({ firstDay: 1,  minDate: weekStart, onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var week = Math.floor(days / 7) % 2;
    $('#week').val(week + 1);
    $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
    $('#work').val(roster[week * 7 + date.getDay() - 1]);
  }});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
<p>Day: <input type="text" id="day"></p>
<p>week: <input type="text" id="week"></p>
<p>work: <input type="text" id="work"></p>

</body>
</html>
```